# Integrating firebase and adwords campaigns

Tags: firebase, google-ads-api

I have an application (in ionic, though that does not seem to matter) and I have been able to send an event to firebase and to see it on adwords (after marking it a conversion event).

My question is: can I cross information? Can I ask something like 'of campaign X, how many users fired conversion action Y'? If so, do I need to do something to be able to write that 'query' - to 'connect' the adwords 'user_id' to firebase somehow, or is it the case that just firing the event to firebase is enough?

(PS: I am a developer, and I do not know much about either firebase or adwords)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/adwords/), you can `Drive installs, gain deep insights into ad conversions, and run targeted ad campaigns using Firebase Analytics audiences to engage your user base.`

`gain deep insights into ad conversions` this looks like what you are looking for.

I suggest you read the above link, which will guide you through how to get AdWords set up on your Firebase app.